Ecobee Aux Heat running only in the early morning hours between 1:30-5:30am
We have only had our ecobee for about 9 months and it was still chilly in March of 2024 so we had ran our heat then as well but this didn’t happen. It only does it in the middle of the night. It has been chilly here in North Georgia but not bad. We have seen temps around 28-36 the last couple weeks. I have tried to turn it to manual and change the set point of when it can come on. I just don’t want to mess anything up and it be a costly repair on a new system.
Does anyone have any advise or can someone walk me through how to correct this please?!?

What is the primary heat source? Does the primary run but not heat up enough or does it not run at all? What is the aux. heat source?

yes, the Ecobee support can walk you through it
